# UPDATE date in PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, date

I have this from on my index file:

```
<form action="index.php#updateMatch" method="post">
    <?php
        Some select option
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;Date: (AAAA-MM-JJ) <input type="date" name="datematch">';
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="do somthing" />
</form>
```

And if I some $_POST[xxx] I call this function:

```
function updateMatch($id,
    $winner_id, 
    $looser_id,
    $character_winner_id, 
    $character_looser_id, 
    $date) {
    database conection......
    $updatematch="UPDATE `match` SET manythings and date=$_POST[datematch] WHERE id=$_POST[id];";
    echo 'match.... N°'.$_POST['id'];
    mysql_close($db);
    }
    else 
        {echo "<span style='color: red'>blablabla</span>";}
}
```

But for date, the update dont work, the function set date to: 0000-00-00. How can i update date to ?
Thanks

Comment: It's many others columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you are missing quotes around your date:

```
$updatematch="UPDATE `match` SET manythings and date=$_POST[datematch] WHERE id=$_POST[id];";
```

should be:

```
$updatematch="UPDATE `match` SET manythings and date='$_POST[datematch]' WHERE id=$_POST[id];";
```

You also have an unecessary column in your statement (`manythings`). Remove it or fix it (I removed it because I don't know of a valid value to use):

```
$updatematch="UPDATE `match` SET date='$_POST[datematch]' WHERE id=$_POST[id];";
```

You are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: You should be careful when direct use of $_POST, you are allowing sql injection attacks

Comment: I know, that's why I mentioned sql injections.

Comment: It's for school, no hacking, don't be worrying

Comment: Thanks, work with the quote: date='$_POST[datematch]'

Comment: @user3414480: _It's for school..._ That's not the point, practice good coding now rather than later.